# Passing a html value as a parameter in react

Tags: html, reactjs, parameters

I need to pass a html value as a parameter for my function like so:

```
<input type ="text" placeholder="Smart Contract Bytecode" name="name" id ="scbytecode"className="nice-textbox"/>

<button id="button" onClick={parseAddress("document.getElementById('smartcontract').value)"}>Submit!</button>
```

but Im getting an error:
TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null

here is the Full code.
Added this to give a better impression of whats going on cause the fixes below don't seem to fix it all. Any help is welcomed.

```
class App extends Component {
  parseAddress(_smartcontract){

    var contractObj = new ethweb3.eth.Contract(ERC20ABI, document.getElementById('smartcontract').value);
      contractObj.getPastEvents(
          'Transfer' || 'allEvents',
          {
              fromBlock: 0,
              toBlock: 'latest'
          },
          function(err,res){
              console.log(err,res);
              //examples to access the data returned
              console.log(res.length);
              document.getElementById("totalAddresses").innerHTML = res.length;
              document.getElementById("sampleAddress").innerHTML = res[0].returnValues.from;
              document.getElementById("sampleAmount").innerHTML = res[0].returnValues.value;
          }
      );
  }
deploSC = async () => {
  const accounts = await goweb3.eth.getAccounts();

//const code = ethweb3.eth.getCode(document.getElementById('smartcontract').value); Not working 
console.log(code);
  goweb3.eth.sendTransaction({
      from: accounts[0],
      data: document.getElementById('scbytecode').value
  }, function(error, hash){
      console.log(error,hash);
  });
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <p>
            Enter the smart contract address:
            <input type="text" name="name" id="smartcontract" className="nice-textbox"/>
            <input type ="text" placeholder="Sc bytecode" name="name" id ="scbytecode"className="nice-textbox"/>
            <button id="button" onClick={this.parseAddress}>Submit!</button>
            <button onClick={this.deploSC}> Deploy Sc</button>
          </p>
          <p id="totalAddresses">0</p>
          <p id="sampleAddress">0</p>
          <p id="sampleAmount">0</p>


        </header>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you mean `parseAddress("document.getElementById('smartcontract').value")`? Notice that `)` comes after `"`

Comment: {parseAddress("document.getElementById('smartcontract').value") returns another error edited answer to correct typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a better way to do this in React using `state` and not directly accessing the DOM which should be avoided.

Store the value of an `input` in the component's state, then give it to the button's onClick event handler via `this.state.inputVal`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
          inputVal: ''
      };
  }

  inputChanged = (e) => {
      this.setState({ inputVal: e.target.value });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input type ="text" placeholder="Smart Contract Bytecode" name="name" id ="scbytecode" className="nice-textbox" onChange={this.inputChanged}/>

        <button id="button" onClick={() => { console.log(this.state.inputVal); }}>Submit!</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Render it
ReactDOM.render(
  <App/>,
  document.getElementById("react")
);
```

```html
<div id="react"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think there is mismatch in id.
line 1 you gave "scbytecode"
line 2 you are trying access by id "smartcontract" which is not present, so you are seeing null